# StreamBuilder hangs when listening to Firestore snapshot

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, subscription

### Steps to Reproduce

I am trying to use the bloc pattern with firebase and having hard time since there is not good tutorial out there which uses `firebase` and `bloc pattern`.

I've faced strange thing while doing this and worked hard to find out the problem but couldn't.

I've created `UserBloc` and tried to set `UserModel` after listening to `Firestore snapshot`.

```
class UserBloc extends Object {
    final _user = StreamController<UserModel>.broadcast();
    final _uid = StreamController<String>.broadcast();

    Stream<UserModel> get user => _user.stream;
    Stream<String> get uid => _uid.stream;

    Function(UserModel) get setUser => _user.sink.add;
    Function(String) get setUID => _uid.sink.add;

    Stream<DocumentSnapshot> userStream;

    UserBloc() {
        uid.listen((uid) {
            print('user : $uid');
            if (uid != null) {
                fromUID(uid);
            }
        });
    }

    fromUID(String uid) {
        print('fromUID');
        userStream = Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(uid).snapshots();

        /// works ok when I delete below subscription
        userStream.listen((data) {
        });
    }

    dispose() {
        _user.close();
        _uid.close();
    }
}
```

Then I used the `StreamBuilder` inside my widget like below.

```
StreamBuilder(
    stream: userBloc.userStream,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
        print(snapshot.connectionState);
        print(snapshot.data);
        return Text('testing');
    },
);
```

The problem is the **`snapshot.connectionState**` is always **`waiting`**. However, when I delete the subscription code which is `userStream.listen((data) {`, I was able to get this working. All the example do the listen and set the data in the constructor of `bloc`. I have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51396947/10269042

Comment: @anmol.maljhail I already tried to expose as broadcast stream. No luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must delete listen-sentence for stream controller in Bloc when you are using Streambuilder. Because Streambuilder is listening stream controller in Bloc, there is a duplication problem between Streambuilder and listen-sentence in Bloc.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that `.snapshot()` returns a BroadcastStream.

https://www.dartlang.org/articles/libraries/broadcast-streams

After the first subscription (`.listen` in constructor) the stream is active and the onData callback is called when data is available/changed.

When the UI subscribes to the stream, the stream is already active (the read operation is done), so the **ConnectionState will always return waiting** till next document update.

Try to modify your code like this, to reproduce:

```
/// works ok when I delete below subscription
userStream.listen((data) => print(data));

Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5),
        () => userStream.listen((onData) => print(onData))
);
```

The second callback will **NOT** fire.

To avoid this behavior, you have to do some caching.

Add rxdart to your dependencies
https://pub.dev/packages/rxdart

Modify your code like this

```
userStream = Observable(Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(uid).snapshots())
.shareReplay(maxSize: 1);
```

> It will replay the emitted values to any new listener, up to a given
>   [maxSize].