# Bad state: Stream has already been listened to

Tags: flutter, dart

While the onBoarding screen is running, as I am trying to edit it, it is just gives the below error:

```
Bad state: Stream has already been listened to.

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  OnBoardingView OnBoardingView:file:///Users/mac/Desktop/My%20Portofolio/saibmob/lib/presentation/resources/routes_manager.dart:32:56
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#6      _StreamBuilderBaseState._subscribe (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart:134:38)
#7      _StreamBuilderBaseState.initState (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart:108:5)
#8      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4893:57)
#9      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4729:5)
#10     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3790:14)
#11     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3524:20)
#12     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4780:16)
#13     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4928:11)
#14     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4477:5)
#15     BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2659:19)
#16     WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:882:21)
#17     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:363:5)
#18     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1144:15)
#19     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1081:9)
#20     SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:995:5)
#24     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:151:10)
#25     PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:308:5)
#26     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:115:31)
(elided 9 frames from dart:async)
====================================================================================================
```

and this is the `OnBoardingView`:

```
import 'package:saibmob/app/app_prefs.dart';
import 'package:saibmob/domain/model/models.dart';
import 'package:saibmob/presentation/onboarding/viewmodel/onboarding_viewmodel.dart';
import 'package:saibmob/presentation/resources/assets_manager.dart';
import 'package:saibmob/presentation/resources/color_manager.dart';
import 'package:saibmob/presentation/resources/routes_manager.dart';
import 'package:saibmob/presentation/resources/strings_manager.dart';
import 'package:saibmob/presentation/resources/values_manager.dart';
import 'package:easy_localization/easy_localization.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/svg.dart';

import '../../../app/di.dart';
import '../../resources/constants_manager.dart';

class OnBoardingView extends StatefulWidget {
  const OnBoardingView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _OnBoardingViewState createState() => _OnBoardingViewState();
}

class _OnBoardingViewState extends State<OnBoardingView> {
  final PageController _pageController = PageController();
  final OnBoardingViewModel _viewModel = OnBoardingViewModel();
  final AppPreferences _appPreferences = instance<AppPreferences>();

  _bind() {
    _appPreferences.setOnBoardingScreenViewed();
    _viewModel.start();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _bind();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<SliderViewObject>(
        stream: _viewModel.outputSliderViewObject,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return _getContentWidget(snapshot.data);
        });
  }

  Widget _getContentWidget(SliderViewObject? sliderViewObject) {
    if (sliderViewObject == null) {
      return Container();
    } else {
      return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: ColorManager.white,
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: ColorManager.white,
          elevation: AppSize.s0,
          systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
              statusBarColor: ColorManager.white,
              statusBarBrightness: Brightness.dark),
        ),
        body: PageView.builder(
            controller: _pageController,
            itemCount: sliderViewObject.numOfSlides,
            onPageChanged: (index) {
              _viewModel.onPageChanged(index);
            },
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return OnBoardingPage(sliderViewObject.sliderObject);
            }),
        bottomSheet: Container(
          color: ColorManager.white,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                child: TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, Routes.loginRoute);
                  },
                  child: Text(
                    AppStrings.skip,
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleMedium,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                  ).tr(),
                ),
              ),

              // widgets indicator and arrows
              _getBottomSheetWidget(sliderViewObject)
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  Widget _getBottomSheetWidget(SliderViewObject sliderViewObject) {
    return Container(
      color: ColorManager.primary,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          // left arrow
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(AppPadding.p14),
            child: GestureDetector(
              child: SizedBox(
                width: AppSize.s20,
                height: AppSize.s20,
                child: SvgPicture.asset(ImageAssets.leftArrowIc),
              ),
              onTap: () {
                // go to previous slide
                _pageController.animateToPage(_viewModel.goPrevious(),
                    duration: const Duration(
                        milliseconds: AppConstants.sliderAnimationTime),
                    curve: Curves.bounceInOut);
              },
            ),
          )

// circle indicator

          // right arrow
          ,
          Row(
            children: [
              for (int i = 0; i < sliderViewObject.numOfSlides; i++)
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(AppPadding.p8),
                  child: _getProperCircle(i, sliderViewObject.currentIndex),
                )
            ],
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(AppPadding.p14),
            child: GestureDetector(
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: AppSize.s20,
                  height: AppSize.s20,
                  child: SvgPicture.asset(ImageAssets.rightArrowIc),
                ),
                onTap: () {
                  // go to previous slide
                  _pageController.animateToPage(_viewModel.goNext(),
                      duration: const Duration(
                          milliseconds: AppConstants.sliderAnimationTime),
                      curve: Curves.bounceInOut);
                }),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _getProperCircle(int index, int currentIndex) {
    if (index == currentIndex) {
      return SvgPicture.asset(ImageAssets.hollowCircleIc);
    } else {
      return SvgPicture.asset(ImageAssets.solidCircleIc);
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _viewModel.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}

class OnBoardingPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final SliderObject _sliderObject;

  const OnBoardingPage(this._sliderObject, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        const SizedBox(height: AppSize.s40),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(AppPadding.p8),
          child: Text(
            _sliderObject.title,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.displayLarge,
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(AppPadding.p8),
          child: Text(
            _sliderObject.subTitle,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: AppSize.s60),
        SvgPicture.asset(_sliderObject.image)
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

and this is the OnBoarding view model:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:ffi';

import 'package:saibmob/domain/model/models.dart';
import 'package:easy_localization/easy_localization.dart';

import '../../base/baseviewmodel.dart';
import '../../resources/assets_manager.dart';
import '../../resources/strings_manager.dart';

class OnBoardingViewModel extends BaseViewModel
    with OnBoardingViewModelInputs, OnBoardingViewModelOutputs {
  // stream controllers outputs
  final StreamController _streamController =
      StreamController<SliderViewObject>();
  late final List<SliderObject> _list;
  int _currentIndex = 0;

  //OnBoarding ViewModel Inputs
  @override
  void dispose() {
    _streamController.close();
  }

  @override
  void start() {
    // view model start your job
    _list = _getSliderData();
    _postDataToView();
  }

  @override
  int goNext() {
    int nextIndex = ++_currentIndex;
    if (nextIndex == _list.length) {
      nextIndex = 0;
    }
    return nextIndex;
  }

  @override
  int goPrevious() {
    int previousIndex = --_currentIndex;
    if (previousIndex == -1) {
      previousIndex = _list.length - 1;
    }
    return previousIndex;
  }

  @override
  void onPageChanged(int index) {
    _currentIndex = index;
    _postDataToView();
  }

  @override
  Sink get inputSliderViewObject => _streamController.sink;

  //OnBoarding ViewModel outputs
  @override
  Stream<SliderViewObject> get outputSliderViewObject =>
      _streamController.stream.map((sliderViewObject) => sliderViewObject);

  // onboarding private functions
  void _postDataToView() {
    inputSliderViewObject.add(
        SliderViewObject(_list[_currentIndex], _list.length, _currentIndex));
  }

  List<SliderObject> _getSliderData() => [
        SliderObject(AppStrings.onBoardingTitle1.tr(),
            AppStrings.onBoardingSubTitle1.tr(), ImageAssets.onboardingLogo1),
        SliderObject(AppStrings.onBoardingTitle2.tr(),
            AppStrings.onBoardingSubTitle2.tr(), ImageAssets.onboardingLogo2),
        SliderObject(AppStrings.onBoardingTitle3.tr(),
            AppStrings.onBoardingSubTitle3.tr(), ImageAssets.onboardingLogo3),
        SliderObject(AppStrings.onBoardingTitle4.tr(),
            AppStrings.onBoardingSubTitle4.tr(), ImageAssets.onboardingLogo4),
      ];
}

// inputs mean that "Orders" that our view model will receive from view
abstract class OnBoardingViewModelInputs {
  int goNext(); // when user clicks on right arrow or swipe left
  int goPrevious(); // when user clicks on left arrow or swipe right
  void onPageChanged(int index);

  // stream controller input
  Sink get inputSliderViewObject;
}

abstract class OnBoardingViewModelOutputs {
  // stream controller output
  Stream<SliderViewObject> get outputSliderViewObject;
}
```

and this is the route manager screen:

```
import 'package:saibmob/presentation/forgot_password/forgot_password_view.dart';
import 'package:saibmob/presentation/login/view/login_view.dart';
import 'package:saibmob/presentation/main/main_view.dart';
import 'package:saibmob/presentation/onboarding/view/onboarding_view.dart';
import 'package:saibmob/presentation/register/view/register_view.dart';
import 'package:saibmob/presentation/resources/strings_manager.dart';
import 'package:saibmob/presentation/splash/splash_view.dart';
import 'package:saibmob/presentation/store_details/store_details_view.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../../app/di.dart';
import 'package:easy_localization/easy_localization.dart';

class Routes {
  static const String splashRoute = "/";
  static const String loginRoute = "/login";
  static const String registerRoute = "/register";
  static const String forgotPasswordRoute = "/forgotPassword";
  static const String onBoardingRoute = "/onBoarding";
  static const String mainRoute = "/main";
  static const String storeDetailsRoute = "/storeDetails";
}

class RouteGenerator {
  static Route<dynamic> getRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    switch (settings.name) {
      case Routes.splashRoute:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => const SplashView());
      case Routes.loginRoute:
        initLoginModule();
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => const LoginView());
      case Routes.onBoardingRoute:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => const OnBoardingView());
      case Routes.registerRoute:
        initRegisterModule();
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => const RegisterView());
      case Routes.forgotPasswordRoute:
        initForgotPasswordModule();
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => const ForgotPasswordView());
      case Routes.mainRoute:
        initHomeModule();
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => const MainView());
      case Routes.storeDetailsRoute:
        initStoreDetailsModule();
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => const StoreDetailsView());
      default:
        return unDefinedRoute();
    }
  }

  static Route<dynamic> unDefinedRoute() {
    return MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (_) => Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                title: Text(AppStrings.noRouteFound.tr()),
              ),
              body: Center(child: Text(AppStrings.noRouteFound.tr())),
            ));
  }
}
```

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I have tried to add .broadcast but it doesn't work

Comment: Can you try adding `.broadcast()` on `StreamController()`

Comment: @YeasinSheikh yes exactly I have tried like this `  final StreamController _streamController =
      StreamController<SliderViewObject>.broadcast();` but doesn't work it shows me a  black screen

Comment: @YeasinSheikh it works after followed this answer thank you :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53841750/flutter-stream-has-already-been-listened-to/55893532#55893532

Comment: You can close this duplicate while the above one solves your issue.