# Trouble with running and hot reloading flutter in Android studio(Bad state: Future already completed)

Tags: flutter

**This issue has been submitted to the Flutter github issues: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27450**

I am having some trouble with running and hot reloading flutter apps in Android studio.

When I run an app in Android studio, I get the following message every now and again(2 out of 3 runs) and the build fails.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone XR in debug mode...
Unhandled exception:
Bad state: Future already completed
#0      _AsyncCompleter.complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:39:31)
#1      _NativeSocket.startConnect.<anonymous closure>.connectNext.<anonymous closure> (dart:io/runtime/binsocket_patch.dart:490:23)
#2      _NativeSocket.issueWriteEvent.issue (dart:io/runtime/binsocket_patch.dart:844:14)
#3      _NativeSocket.issueWriteEvent (dart:io/runtime/binsocket_patch.dart:851:12)
#4      _NativeSocket.multiplex (dart:io/runtime/binsocket_patch.dart:872:11)
#5      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:171:12)
```

I have not been able to get hot reload to work at all

```
Performing hot reload...
Syncing files to device iPhone XR...
Unhandled exception:
Bad state: Future already completed
#0      _AsyncCompleter.complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:39:31)
#1      _NativeSocket.startConnect.<anonymous closure>.connectNext.<anonymous closure> (dart:io/runtime/binsocket_patch.dart:490:23)
#2      _NativeSocket.issueWriteEvent.issue (dart:io/runtime/binsocket_patch.dart:844:14)
#3      _NativeSocket.issueWriteEvent (dart:io/runtime/binsocket_patch.dart:851:12)
#4      _NativeSocket.multiplex (dart:io/runtime/binsocket_patch.dart:872:11)
#5      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:171:12)
```

I am working on the stable channel. Here is my output of flutter doctor:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.0.0, on Mac OS X 10.14.1 18B75, locale en-AU)
• Flutter version 1.0.0 at /Users/rakshak/flutter
• Framework revision 5391447fae (9 weeks ago), 2018-11-29 19:41:26 -0800
• Engine revision 7375a0f414
• Dart version 2.1.0 (build 2.1.0-dev.9.4 f9ebf21297)

⣽Unhandled exception:
Bad state: Future already completed
#0      _AsyncCompleter.complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:39:31)
#1      _NativeSocket.startConnect.<anonymous closure>.connectNext.<anonymous closure> (dart:io/runtime/binsocket_patch.dart:490:23)
#2      _NativeSocket.issueWriteEvent.issue (dart:io/runtime/binsocket_patch.dart:844:14)
#3      _NativeSocket.issueWriteEvent (dart:io/runtime/binsocket_patch.dart:851:12)
#4      _NativeSocket.multiplex (dart:io/runtime/binsocket_patch.dart:872:11)
#5      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:171:12)
```

I am working from China at the moment, I have implemented the changes mentioned here: https://flutter.io/community/china. Here are the relevant parts of my .bash_profile file

```
export PUB_HOSTED_URL=https://pub.flutter-io.cn
export FLUTTER_STORAGE_BASE_URL=https://storage.flutter-io.cn
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/rakshak/flutter/bin
```

I am working on a Mac.

Comment: Submit an issue to https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new

Comment: Done: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27450

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51396769/flutter-bad-state-stream-has-already-been-listened-to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have been a network related issue.

My fix for this: 
I have removed PUB_HOSTED_URL and FLUTTER_STORAGE_BASE_URL from my .bash_profile file and turned on my VPN.

It looks like you need an active and stable internet connection to build and hot reload a flutter app in development.

Related links:

- [Issue I posted on GitHub after a comment on this question](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27450)
- [Similar issue on GitHub](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27696)

Answer (score 2):

This might look like a weird suggestion; however, did you try using vpn while completing this action? I once faced this problem, then using a vpn connection helped me. I guess, you may give it a try.

Comment: Yeh, I think ill comment out the PUB_HOSTED_URL and FLUTTER_STORAGE_BASE_URL from my bask profile and just use a VPN.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a proxy, set the environment variable

```
NO_PROXY=127.0.0.1,localhost
```

Comment: I am not using a proxy.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you to install again flutter following the steps used in
 this popular flutter course video. I hope it will be worth watching
 for you and your error will be removed [Flutter Installation Guide](https://youtu.be/GLSG_Wh_YWc?t=455)
 As you are from China, so you have to add these steps as mentioned in
 the link [Using Flutter In China](https://flutter.io/community/china)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have followed the installation steps from the Flutter dev site. I have also implemented the steps in the "Using flutter in China" link. It didn't seem to help.