# Bad state: Stream has already been listened to flutter provider

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

I'm using [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) to loading json data and refresh app state when any operation performed.

This is my Provider ChangeNotifier

```
    class ClassesDetails with ChangeNotifier {

    Future<void> getLiveClassList(String token) async {
    final url = FitApis.demoBaseURL + "live/class";
    try {
      final response = await http.get(url, headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Authorization': token,
      });
      //print(response.body);
      final responseData = json.decode(response.body);
      if (responseData['data'] != null) {
        notifyListeners();
        Map typesMap = jsonDecode(response.body);
        var types = new LiveClassListModel.fromJson(typesMap);
        _liveClassController.add(types);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      throw (error);
    }
  }

  final _liveClassController = StreamController<LiveClassListModel>();

  Stream<LiveClassListModel> get liveClassStream {
    return _liveClassController.stream;
  }

  void refreshLiveClasses(String token) {
    getLiveClassList(token);
  }
}
```

This is [getIt](https://pub.dev/packages/get_it) used for access provider objects

```
final getIt = GetIt.instance;

void setup() {

  getIt.registerSingleton<ClassesDetails>(ClassesDetails());
  
}
```

Method call to get data

```
    Future<void> getLiveClassList() async {
    final classProvider = getIt<ClassesDetails>();
    
    classProvider.getLiveClassList("token)";
            classProvider.liveClassStream.listen((snapshot) { });
}
```

Refreshing data

```
 classProvider
            .refreshLiveClasses("token");
```

This is working perfectly. But the issue is that when i logout from app and login again it gives me error **Bad state: Stream has already been listened to**. I searched alot but not get helpful solution. I tried [Flutter : Bad state: Stream has already been listened to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51396769/flutter-bad-state-stream-has-already-been-listened-to) but not working. I tried to  classProvider.closeStream() but not working. Please help me how I solve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just created a same stream and found the issue, just change your `StreamController` like this:

```
final _liveClassController = StreamController<LiveClassListModel>.broadcast();
```