# Manage Global Events by bloc

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I am trying to find solution to manage async queries. For example, i have internet shop and i want to update all products and categories when city is changed. And i don't want to keep all async logic on ui. In order to achieve this result, i've created this bloc:

```
class AppEvent {
  String message;

  AppEvent({this.message = ''});
}

class EventsBlock extends Bloc<AppEvent, AppEvent> {
  EventsBlock() : super(AppEvent());
 
  @override
  Stream<AppEvent> mapEventToState(AppEvent event) async* {
    yield event;
  }
}

final events = EventsBlock();
```

Then, i can use it like this:

```
class CityCubit() {
  CityCubit() : super(CityState());  
  
  Future<void> changeCity() async {
    await api.changeCity();
    events.add(AppEvent(message: 'cityChanged'));   
  }
}

class CategoryCubit extends Cubit<CategoryState> {
  CategoryCubit() : super(CategoryEmptyState()) {
    events.stream.listen((e) {
        if(e.message == 'cityChanged') {
            fetchCategories();
        }
      });
  };

  Future<void> fetchCategories() async {
    //fetch categories
  }
}

class ProductCubit extends Cubit<ProductState> {
  ProductCubit() : super(ProductEmptyState()) {
    events.stream.listen((e) {
        if(e.message == 'cityChanged') {
            fetchProducts();
        }
      });
  };

  Future<void> fetchProducts() async {
    //fetch products
  }
}
```

It's something like eventBus pattern. But i am not sure that it's a correct way to use bloc. I've tried to use redux + redux saga, but it has a lot of boilerplate and i believe that flutter has better solution to manage things like that.

Answer (score 1):

Your general idea is ok, but I can't see a real need for the `EventsBloc` class. In fact, it is kinda strange that you use the same class for the events and for the states of this bloc, and simply yield the event you receive. It's like `EventsBloc` could be a simple stream.

Here's a way to go, turning `CityCubit` into an actual bloc (and also with some error handling, which is something you can do gracefully with bloc):

```
abstract class CityState {}
class CityInitial extends CityState {}
class CityLoadingCities extends CityState {}
class CityCitiesLoaded extends CityState {}
class CityLoadError extends CityState {}

abstract class CityEvent {}
class CityLoadCities extends CityEvent {}

class CityBloc<CityEvent, CityState> {
  CityBloc() : super(CityInitial());  

  @override
  Stream<AppEvent> mapEventToState(CityEvent event) async* {
    if(event is CityLoadCities) {
      yield CityLoadingCities();
      try {
        await api.changeCity();
        yield CityCitiesLoaded();
      } catch (error) {
        yield CityLoadError();
      }
    }
  }
  
  void changeCity() {
    add(CityLoadCities());   
  }
}
```

Now you can do this inside any other bloc:

```
instanceOfCityBloc.listen((cityState) {
  if(cityState is CityCitiesLoaded){
    // do stuff
  }
});
```

Comment: The problem is that i need to inject instance of cityBloc on every page(categories, products etc). And i have to do it inside widget build, pass it to other bloc/cubit constructor

Comment: what if i make singleton of this block and listen events directly in others classes? Will it be correct way?

Comment: I think i found solution https://pub.dev/packages/event_bus.

Comment: I do not agree to the proposed solution here because the Bloc will be aware of other blocs and breaks the architecture layer. Just use the EventBus directly within the bloc constructor, listen to some eventbus event then add a new event to your current bloc. This way the bloc will not know or listen to other blocs

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with this code:

```
class CityChangedEvent {
  int cityId;

  CityChangedEvent(this.cityId);
}

EventBus eventBus = EventBus();

mixin EventBusMixin {
  StreamSubscription<T> listenEvent<T>(void Function(T) subscription) =>
      eventBus.on<T>().listen(subscription);

  void shareEvent<S>(S event) => eventBus.fire(event);
}

class CityCubit extends CityCubit<CityState> with EventBusMixin {
  CityCubit() : super(CityInitialState());        

  Future<void> changeCity(cityId) async {
    try {
      emit(ChangeCityLoadingState());
      final result = await api.changeCity(cityId);
      if(result.success) {
        emit(ChangeCitySuccessState());
        shareEvent(CityChangedEvent(cityId));   
      }
    } catch (_) {
      emit(ChangeCityErrorState());
    }
  }
}

class CategoryCubit extends Cubit<CategoryState> with EventBusMixin {
  CategoryCubit() : super(CategoryEmptyState()) {
     listenEvent<CityChangedEvent>((e) {
        fetchCategories(e.cityId);
     );
  }

  Future<void> fetchCategories(cityId) async {
    try {
      emit(CategoryLoadingState());
      final categoriesList = await fetchCategoriesApi();
      emit(CategoryLoadedState(categories: categoriesList));
    } catch (_) {
      emit(CategoryErrorState());
    }
  }
}
```

Now, i can communicate between blocs without the need to instantiate or inject their instances. Thanks to this library https://pub.dev/packages/event_bus

Answer (score 0):

In response to https://stackoverflow.com/a/67398924/5638943 I am sharing my concerns then two solutions which I think respect the clean architecture.

**Concern:**
This works but it is not clean architecture as the bloc is responsible for knowing with who to share what instead of "minding its own business"

**My recommended solutions**

**Solution 1:** I do recommend to use application layer service instead that listens to this bloc and other bloc events and decides what is important to be shared through the event bus. The CategoryCubit looks totally fine it is a clean pattern to listen an event bus within the bloc.

**Solution 2:** Use application layer orchestrator that listens to events of CityCubit and if city is changed, will emit event in categoriescubit to refetch the categories.