# Black screen when switching "TabBarView" with `StreamBuilder` children

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

When you switch back to a tab you get a black screen,
does anyone know why?

[Check on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=7bb130002eec1284dc63a72978a990d5)

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: MyStatelessWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyStatelessWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      initialIndex: 1,
      length: 3,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('TabBar Widget'),
          bottom: const TabBar(
            tabs: <Widget>[
              Tab(
                icon: Icon(Icons.cloud_outlined),
              ),
              Tab(
                icon: Icon(Icons.beach_access_sharp),
              ),
              Tab(
                icon: Icon(Icons.brightness_5_sharp),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: <Widget>[
            StreamBuilder(
              stream: Stream.value(true),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                return const Center(child: Text("It's cloudy here"));
              },
            ),
            StreamBuilder(
              stream: Stream.value(true),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                return const Center(child: Text("It's rainy here"));
              },
            ),
            StreamBuilder(
              stream: Stream.value(true),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                return const Center(child: Text("It's sunny here"));
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this similar question while both throw the same error

> [Bad state: Stream has already been listened to](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51396769/10157127)

You can find there some good explanation about  this issue.

As for this question, you can use `initialData: true,` instead of using `stream`.

```dart
StreamBuilder(
  initialData: true,
  //...
),
```

If you can also use `StreamController` with adding `broadcast`
like `StreamController<T>.broadcast()`.

You can follow [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51396769/10157127).